# Problems tapping UIBarButtonItem if flexible spacer used in iOS 7

Tags: user-interface, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, user-experience

I have to reask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236869/how-to-improve-tap-ability-of-buttons-on-toolbars-and-navigation-bars-in-ios-7) as I have more info than before.

I have a UIToolbar at the bottom of a view, it has the following:

UIBarButtonItem (custom) [flexible space] UISegmentedControl [flexible space] UIBarButtonItem (Add)

On the lower right is the + for ADD as described above.  Due to the use of the flexible space type UIBarButtonItem to get the UISegmented control centered, this affecs the tapability of the + button.  Users are finding it very hard to tap in iOS 7.

If you just have a button left and right then iOS 7 does extend the tapable area quite nicely, you can tap a good distance away from the button.  But with the flexible spacers this is not the case and it's frustrating my users.

How do you suggest I fix this to make the + button more tapable?

Thank you.

Comment: You can add FixedSpace after + button, that would make you more clickable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try using a UINavigationBar instead of the UIToolbar. The segmented control would be in the titleView of the navigation bar's top navigation item.

[image: Screenshot showing a UINavigationBar with left and right bar button items and a segmented control as the title view]

With this setup, the + button is tappable as far left as about halfway to the segmented control.